# removing the vertical scroll bar in a jscrollpane?

Tags: java, jscrollpane

Is it possible to remove the vertical scroll bar in a JScrollPane?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
JScrollPane.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_NEVER);
```